# How do I reset 'master' to 'origin/master'?

Tags: git

Can I do the following in a simpler way?

```
git checkout origin/master
git branch -D master
git branch master
git checkout master
```

Comment: Sometimes, this can be done without touching the working tree: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12343727/586086

Comment: Please update your accepted answer: @KindDragon’s answer is correcter and shorter.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Git supports this command:

```
git checkout -B master origin/master
```

Check out the `origin/master` branch and then reset `master` branch there.

UPDATE:
Or you can use new switch command for that

```
git switch -C master origin/master
```

Comment: The only true answer.

Comment: save four keystrokes -- you don't need the quotes.   Just: git checkout -B master origin/master

Comment: let's says I commited 2 things, the first one is a merge with branch and the second one is regular. What happens to the merge if I go back to the origin/master?

Comment: don't you have to `git fetch origin master` before to be sure `origin/master` is updated?

Comment: Yes, of course with all solutions you should do `git fetch` first

Comment: won't this lose commits on the local master as you reset it to origin/master? usually people get to this point when they committed stuff directly onto master by mistake, and wish they had branched previously.

Comment: @MottiShneor: Yes, it will lose all new activity on local `master`.  Which is what the question asks for.

Comment: I tried this, but I still have local changes not reflected in origin. should my local changes  not have reverted to origin/master?

Answer (score 393):

As [KindDragon](https://superuser.com/users/64719/kinddragon)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/802416/141) mentions, you can recreate `master` directly at `origin/master` with:

```
git checkout -B master origin/master
```

The [`git checkout` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)  mentions:

If `-B` is given, `<new_branch>` is created if it doesn’t exist; **otherwise, it is reset**. This is the transactional equivalent of

```
$ git branch -f <branch> [<start point>]
$ git checkout <branch>
```

---

Since Git 2.23+ (August 2019), since [`git checkout` is too confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309), the new (still experimental) command is **[`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch)**:

```
git switch -C master origin/master
```

That is:

> ```
> -C <new-branch>
> --force-create <new-branch>
> ```
>
> Similar to `--create` except that if `<new-branch>` already exists, it will be reset to `<start-point>`.
>   This is a convenient shortcut for:
>
> ```
> $ git branch -f <new-branch>
> $ git switch <new-branch>
> ```

---

*Originally suggested:*

Something like:

```
$ git checkout master

# remember where the master was referencing to
$ git branch previous_master

# Reset master back to origin/master
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

with step 2 being optional.

Comment: You can do that with one line.

Comment: Thank you VonC, I have updated to accept @KindDragon's answer as dear of you suggested. The technique is always advancing. It's already __10 YEARS__!! Love you guys!!   ^_^

Comment: @XièJìléi No problem, good choice. Mine adds more details to KindDragon's.

Answer (score 31):

I think even VonC's answer has complexity compared to this option:

```
git update-ref refs/heads/master origin/master
git reset --hard master
```

git automatically logs every value of a ref (through the reflog). So after you run that command, then `master@{1}` refers to the previous value of master.

VonC's answer is correct, but it wastes time checkout out the old value of master into the filesystem.

If you care about orphaned objects in the repo, then you can run `git gc`

Comment: Sounds an interesting alternative. +1

Comment: I still get `Already on 'master'`

Comment: @yourfriendzak, I forgot about taking into account that you might already have master checked out before updating master. I have updated the answer to be one that should work even in that case as well.

Comment: This works even if you're not on master (like a detached HEAD state that is actually pointing to the tip origin/master). Then, you can checkout master without having to flip old files through the repo. Great!

Answer (score 31):

If you are already on `master` you can do the following:

`git reset --hard origin/master`

It will point the local `master` branch to the remote `origin/master` and discard any modifications in the working dir.

Comment: And will delete files! If you have created/edited files, and have run a "git add" on them, this command will delete them.  Be warned.

Comment: Is this approach better than `git checkout -B master origin/master` ?